# How to select max spending customer per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view that lists the date, customerID, orderID, and orderCost.
How do I select the max spending customer per month?
The data only spans a period of six months in year 2015.

I am able to get the SUM spent by each customer each month but not the max spending customer with:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year, MONTHNAME(date) AS month, customerID, SUM(orderCost) 
FROM CustomerPricedOrder 
GROUP BY MONTH(date), customerID;
```

*where CustomerPricedOrder is a view that takes data from a table entitled CustomerOrder

How can I find the max spending customer per month with a stored procedure?
Do i need a cursor?

An example of the output I require when I call the procedure:

- year........month.........customerID
- 2015........January.......4
- 2015........February......21
- 2015........March.........6
- 2015........April.........11

where customerID is the highest spending customer of that month.

Comment: This is a well known problem, see the tag 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 3):

Can you just order by sum descending and limit 1?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year, MONTHNAME(date) AS month, customerID, SUM(orderCost) as sum_of_order_cost FROM CustomerPricedOrder GROUP BY MONTH(date), customerID order by sum_of_order_cost desc limit 1;
```

Comment: `order by sum_of_order_cost` would give you an invalid identifier error.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year, 
MONTHNAME(date) AS month, 
customerID, 
SUM(orderCost) as sum_order_cost, 
MAX(sum_of_order_cost) FROM CustomerPricedOrder 
GROUP BY MONTH(date), customerID 
order by sum_order_cost DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This might work

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

Can you please try this

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year, MONTHNAME(date) AS month, customerID, SUM(orderCost) AS cost 
FROM CustomerPricedOrder 
GROUP BY MONTH(date), customerID ORDER BY cost DESC;
```

If my brain understood correctly this should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using variables to simulate `row_number()`. The query ranks each customer within a group (where each group represents a month) starting from 1 for the highest spending customer, and keeps those with rank 1:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @rn := if(@prevMonth = month AND @prevYear = year, @rn + 1, 1) rn, 
           @prevMonth := month, @prevYear := year, *
    FROM ( 
        SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, 
            MONTHNAME(date) AS month, 
            customerID, 
            SUM(orderCost) AS sum_order_cost
        FROM CustomerPricedOrder 
        GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date), YEAR(date), customerID
    ) t ORDER BY year, month, sum_order_cost desc
) t WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year, 
MONTHNAME(date) AS month, 
customerID, 
SUM(orderCost) as sum_of_order_cost, 
MAX(sum_of_order_cost) FROM CustomerPricedOrder 
GROUP BY MONTH(date), customerID 
order by orderCost;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a straight forward application of analytic functions

```
    select year, month, customer, amount,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY year, month ORDER BY amount DESC) rn
    (
          SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year, MONTHNAME(date) AS month,customerID, SUM(orderCost) amount
          FROM CustomerPricedOrder 
          GROUP BY MONTH(date), customerID
    ) 

;
```

This will rank the amount per year / month with the highest amount assigned `rn -> 1`. General question you need to be aware of when using analytic functions is how you want to deal with "equal results" (i.e. two customers with the same amount in a period). Check whether that case needs to be handled and whether Row_Number is better suited to your needs (forces unique numbering even for equal results, whereas `rank()` will assign the same order number for equal results), or you need to add to the sort criteria in the analytic function.